# limit slimbox (lightbox) image to window size

Tags: jquery, lightbox, slimbox

HI all,

Anyone know how to limit the overlay window size of slimbox to be a percentage of the user's window size (like prettyphoto does)

Thanks

Here's the module code:
http://paste.ly/3Kz

And the slimbox js:
http://paste.ly/3L0

Comment: wow, your homepage looks Awesome with cool Animation :)

Comment: thanks, I'm probably not going to use it myself - but will finish it up and release it as a gnu/gpl portfolio page once i'm finished.

Comment: I like your site too but the left/right arrows don't seem to do anything (Safari).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

capture the users window resolution and set the overlay's width and height according to captured info...

```
$('#overlay').width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
```

Comment: Where would I plug this?
I'm trying to adjust images that are dynamically called from a module in Joomla - and usually i can figure our the jquery, but in this instance, i'm stumped

Comment: I didn't get you :( can u show your actual code (or) a screen shot of the module , I mean in which module are you going to use this ?

Answer (score 6):

Actually neither of your solutions quite  did it for me , so i had to put them in a blender and sorta mix the result by doing this:

as he said, look out for this lines in slimbox2.js

```
w(g).css({backgroundImage:"url("+n+")",visibility:"hidden",display:""});
w(p).width(k.width);
w([p,I,d]).height(k.height);
```

and replace them with this block:

```
        var winWidth  = window.innerWidth  - 20;
        var winHeight = window.innerHeight - 120;
        if (winWidth > winHeight) { 
            var maxSize = winHeight; 
        } else { 
            var maxSize = winWidth;
        }

        /* determine proper w and h for img, based on original image'w dimensions and maxSize */
        var my_w = k.width; 
        var my_h = k.height;            

        if (my_w > my_h) {
            my_h = maxSize * my_h / my_w;
            my_w = maxSize;
        } else {
            my_w = maxSize * my_w / my_h;
            my_h = maxSize;
        }

        if (k.width > my_w || k.height > my_h){ /* constrain it */
            w(g).css({backgroundImage:"url("+n+")",backgroundSize:""+my_w+"px "+my_h+"px",visibility:"hidden",display:""});
            w(p).width(my_w);
            w([p,I,d]).height(my_h);    
        }
        else { /* default behaviour  NORMAL before hackeing*/
            w(g).css({backgroundImage:"url("+n+")",backgroundSize:"",visibility:"hidden",display:""});
            w(p).width(k.width);
            w([p,I,d]).height(k.height);            
        }
```

*be kind, i'm an amateur developer on early stage ;)

Comment: Works, but won't this get overwritten if the plugin is updated?

Comment: AMAZING ! Thanks a lot for this code :-)

Made my day ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to use Redscouse's solution but I think his used an older version of slimbox.  Here is a solution based on v2.04 that will constrain the image to fit inside the current browser window.

Locate the animateBox() function.  Near the top you should find lines that look like this:

```
$(image).css({backgroundImage: "url(" + activeURL + ")", visibility: "hidden", display: ""});
$(sizer).width(preload.width);
$([sizer, prevLink, nextLink]).height(preload.height);
```

Replace those lines with these:

```
/* make sure the image won't be bigger than the window */
var winWidth = $(window).width() - 20;
var winHeight = $(window).height() - 104;
var maxSize = (winWidth > winHeight) ? winHeight : winWidth; /* the smaller dimension determines max size */

/* determine proper w and h for img, based on original image'w dimensions and maxSize */
var my_w = preload.width; 
var my_h = preload.height;
if (my_w > my_h)
{
    my_h = maxSize * my_h / my_w;
    my_w = maxSize;
}
else
{
    my_w = maxSize * my_w / my_h;
    my_h = maxSize;
}

if (preload.width > my_w || preload.height > my_h){ /* constrain it */
    $(image).css({backgroundImage: "url(" + activeURL + ")", backgroundSize: my_w + "px " + my_h + "px", visibility: "hidden", display: ""});
    $(sizer).width(my_w);
    $([sizer, prevLink, nextLink]).height(my_h);
}
else { /* default behaviour */
    $(image).css({backgroundImage: "url(" + activeURL + ")", backgroundSize: "", visibility: "hidden", display: ""});
    $(sizer).width(preload.width);
    $([sizer, prevLink, nextLink]).height(preload.height);
}
```

The -20 and -104 adjustments are to take into account extra space that slimbox uses around the image.  Feel free to tweak those as needed.

Comment: It's worth noting that this code is for Slimbox + jQuery. I've managed to use the same principle for getting it working with some legacy code still using Slimbox v1.58 and MooTools v1.11

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where the image was expanding beyond the size of the window. I know I could of solved this by restricting the size of the image on upload, but I didn't want to do that, I would rather be able to set the size of slimbox window so I set about the task, here's what I came up with and it works perfectly! :)

To make it easier to adjust in the future you want to add the userDefinedWidth and userDefinedHeight lines to your call to slimbox in the options:

Example:

```
$(function($) {
    $("a[rel^='lightbox']").slimbox({
    /* Put custom options here */
    userDefinedWidth:640, /* set max width here */
    userDefinedHeight:480, /* set max height here */
    initialWidth: 250,
    initialHeight: 250,
    imageFadeDuration: 400
});
```

Next, Open slimbox.js (or slimbox2.js) and look for the options again, this time add the userDefinedWidth and userDefinedHeight with no values like so:

```
w.slimbox=function(O,N,M){
    u=w.extend({
    userDefinedWidth:'',
    userDefinedHeight:'',
    loop:false,
    ...etc.
    ...etc.
```

Next find the function called i.
In the i function replace the following lines:

```
w(g).css({backgroundImage:"url("+n+")",visibility:"hidden",display:""});
w(p).width(k.width); 
w([p,I,d]).height(k.height);
```

with these lines:

```
var my_w = u.userDefinedWidth; 
var my_h = u.userDefinedHeight;
w(g).css({backgroundImage:"url("+n+")",backgroundSize:""+my_w+"px "+my_h+"px",visibility:"hidden",display:""});
w(p).width(my_w);
w([p,I,d]).height(my_h);
```

Once you have done that, you're good to go and should be able to resize the slimbox to a setting of your choice.

Pete.

PS: I'm a php guy getting to grips with jquery/javascript so if anyone can make this better/quicker/easier please feel free. Oh, and please feel free to use this code anywhere you like. ;)

Comment: Hi guys, the version i am using is indeed Slimbox v2.04 and the changes i made work just fine for me, i can set the window to whatever size i wish. I assume more could be done to resize the actual image instead of the container but it does what i need it to so i never went any further.

Answer (score 0):

While Avinash's response works, this is much more simple:

```
.pp_overlay {max-width:100%; max-height:100%;}
```

The percent in the above fields takes it as a percent of the user's browser size.

The class .pp_overlay is what it is called in PrettyPhoto. You will need to find the equivalent for slimbox.